# Pass parameter value from one function to another in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, parameters, parameter-passing

The following function contains a navigation parameter that represents a value passed from the previous page

```
 protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {

            QuizArgs args = navigationParameter as QuizArgs;
            var SectorGroups = QuizDataSource.GetGroups(args.sector);
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = SectorGroups;
        }

        void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

             var itemId = ((QuizGroups)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
            var sectorId = new QuizArgs
            {
                sector = "nav",

                question = 2,
                Total = 0,
                type=itemId
            };


            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Quiz), sectorId);


        }
```

`QuizArgs` is a class that contains the items to always be passed when navigating between pages.

```
class QuizArgs
{
    public string sector;

    public int Total;
    public int question;
    public string type;

}
```

I want to use the `Object navigationParameter` value from the `LoadState` function in the click function.

I want to assign `sector` to the value in the navigation parameter instead of string "nav".

How do I do use `args.sector` in the click function?

Comment: I started typing up an answer in which the QuizArgs are saved as an object parameter in your Form/Page/whatever, but how well that would work really depends on the lifetime of this UI object you're writing. Could we get a little more background?

Comment: see the edit above, does this help?

Comment: No, it dosen't help. He wants to know about the environment. If it is web forms have an X way, if it is windows forms have another way.

Comment: @Tester Sorry, but no. What QuizArgs is doesn't matter much, but I'm wondering about the Form/Page object definition that contains "LoadState" and "ItemView_ItemClick". I just haven't worked with Windows 8 coding; the basic case is that this object would hold the QuizArgs instance, but that may not be the correct place to store it if this is a different UI object (would survive too long, not long enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
    public class YourClass: YourBaseClass
    {
        QuizArgs args = null;
        protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {

            args = navigationParameter as QuizArgs;
            var SectorGroups = QuizDataSource.GetGroups(args.sector);
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = SectorGroups;
        }

        void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
             if(args == null)
                 throw new NullReferenceException();

             var itemId = args.UniqueId;
             var sectorId = new QuizArgs
             {
                 sector = "nav",
                 question = 2,
                 Total = 0,
                 type=itemId
             };


             this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Quiz), sectorId);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare args as global.Then args would be accesible in both the functions.

Comment: Do you mean class level variable?  A global is available to the entire program.